# Two divs positions

Tags: css, html, position

I'm using google maps for the page. I have to set up the layer with map with 100% height in 100% width minus 200 px for the toolbar to the left:

```
<div id="toolbar" style="float: left;width: 20%">left</div> 
<div id="map" style="float: left;width: 80%;height: 100%;"></div>
```

This code works, but the toolbar resizes. And I need only 200 px there. How can I do that saving the positioning of the map?
The code:

```
<html> 
    <head> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
        <style> 
            body, html
            {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }

            body
            {
                margin: 0;
            }
        </style> 
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <script> 
            $(document).ready(function () {
                    var city = new google.maps.LatLng(56.3, 44)

                    var mapOptions = {
                        zoom: 12,
                        center: city,
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                    }
                    map = new google.maps.Map($('#map').get(0), mapOptions)
            })
        </script> 
        <div id="toolbar" style="float: left;width: 20%">left</div> 
        <div id="map" style="float: left;width: 80%;height: 100%;"></div>
    </body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was flaking a little in Safari, so I had to wrap the #map div in another div to resolve the issue. Try this:

```
<html> 
    <head> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
        <style> 
            body, html
            {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }

            body
            {
                margin: 0;
            }
        </style> 
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <script> 
            $(document).ready(function () {
                    var city = new google.maps.LatLng(56.3, 44)

                    var mapOptions = {
                        zoom: 12,
                        center: city,
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                    }
                    map = new google.maps.Map($('#map').get(0), mapOptions)
            })
        </script> 
        <div id="toolbar" style="float: left; width: 200px;">left</div> 
        <div style="margin-left: 200px;">
            <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
        </div>
    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: There is horizontal scrollbar now.

Comment: Hmm...is it about 200 pixels of horizontal scroll? Also, do you still have width: 100% in the #map style?

Comment: yeah, the scroll is ~200 pixels

Comment: Make sure that the div with the id of map doesn't have width: 100%; in it's styles. I'm assuming that is what is causing the horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: @brian-ray now it has the 200px area to the right of the map.

Answer (score 0):

try this if you are not using css reset:

```
<div id="toolbar" style="float: left;width: 20%;margin:0;padding:0">left 
<div id="map" style="float: left;width: 80%;height: 100%;margin:0;padding:0">
```

Comment: The toolbar changes it's own size when resizing

Comment: The OP wants the toolbar to be 200px, not 20%.